# Commas to separate two phrases separated by conjunctions

Tags: commas, independent-clauses

So I was studying for the grammar (English) section of the ACT, and I discovered what seems to be a serious gap in my knowledge. In one particular section, there were 4 questions that I got wrong - all for essentially the same reason.

Examples speak louder than explanation, so:

> Q: For centuries, scientists believed in the existence of planets beyond the solar ***system, but*** had no way of knowing how common they were or how similar they might be to better-known planets.

The objective of this question was to modify the statement to correct the grammar.

> Choices:
>
> - No change
> - system. But
> - system but
> - system but they

Now, for me, this question was unambiguously 'No change;' however, apparently not - the answer key says that the correct response is 'system but.'

This was not an isolated occurrence, I realized whilst checking my responses.

> Q: The group was originally a four-person ***ensemble but has expanded to five-part harmonies, a sixth member acts as a sign-language interpreter.***
>
> My Ans: ensemble, but has expanded to five-part harmonies...
>
> Correct Ans: ensemble but has expanded to five-part harmonies...

and

> Q: The rings spread over hundreds of thousands of ***miles, they consist*** of billions of individual particles that create waves, turbulence and other effects.
>
> My Ans: miles, and consist
>
> Correct Ans: miles, and they consist

This question is *slightly* different, yes, but my original question still applies. Also note how the author leaves out the Oxford comma - something I would not do.

Lastly:

> Q: I would live with a local family, and attend classes at a nearby high school.
>
> My ans: No change
>
> Correct ans: family and attend

Thoughts?

Comment: Thank for the answer selected vote. If you ask another question might I suggest waiting 24 hours before selecting an answer as accepted? I don't mean to appear ungrateful but if people see an answer has been accepted they are less likely to give a different, better answer. Waiting 24 hours gives everybody a chance to wake up, go to work, and then spend all our work hours answering questions instead of doing our jobs. :)

Comment: Ahh good advice indeed. I shall re-select your vote soon if none better appear. I commend your virtuousness in suggesting this - I feel as though many would not do what you have, instead preferring to just take the selection and move on.  I would upvote, but I do not have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you an American? Was the test written by a Briton? Examples 1, 2 and 4 are very much the distinction between the BrE and AmE. BrE typically excludes the comma when two independent clauses are conjoined.

As regards the third example, though I don't suppose it would have been amongst the answer options, also correct, in my opinion, would have been:

> The rings spread over hundreds of thousands of **miles and consist** of
>   billions of individual particles...

No pronoun or comma.

The answer you cite appears to me to be inconsistent and idiosyncratic. It appears the examiner has a rule that

- a conjunction is required to join two independent clauses
- and a comma does not precede this conjunction

but then adds to it

- unless that conjunction precedes a pronoun referring to the first clause.

Comment: I am American, and to my knowledge, the writer of this was an American as well. Specifically, Erica Meltzer. She is a test writer and created these questions in preparation for the English ACT. The ACT is a standardized test not unlike the SAT. Are these questions representative of BrE? That surprises me considerably... I notice that in your analysis of the third question, you neglect the comma - are you British? Lastly, do these seem to be standard rules?

Comment: @Equinox To the best of my knowledge, examples 1, 2 and 4 are typically British and I agree with the answers the examiner gave. But, they are more a matter of taste than of grammar. As I note in my answer, BrE tends to omit the commas but even so, unless I had a style guide to which to adhere, I would hesitate to mark them as wrong. Example 3 is simply awkward. I speak a mixture of American and British English caused by migration of my family and my elementary teachers. I prefer to say I *omit* rather than *neglect* the comma; I do it on purpose rather than through carelessness. :)

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much indeed. :) I shall take this all to note - hopefully I will not have to face such a deciding situation on the real test. As for your last sentence, I used 'neglect' with haste, and I apologise. In hindsight, I meant to use 'omit,' but the word did not immediately spring to mind. @ below, I might very well do that. I have noticed other errata throughout, repeated words, numbers etc, and a note to the editor suggesting corrections for the next edition would be useful. A note: this book, 2nd ed. 'The complete guide to the ACT English' is regarded as one of the best.

Comment: If the publisher has a contact address, I would consider contacting them to see if they produce explanatory notes because a test written for an American reader should give typically American answers and they don't seem right to me. If I was doing the test I would have attempted to think American and so would have given the answers you gave to 1, 2 and 4. :) I was teasing you about omit/neglect. I knew what you meant. Please, no apology needed.